# How to ignore duplicate "_id" and insert unique "_id" in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mean

I have a JSON structure at first insertion as

```
collection.insert(query.query, function(err, docs) {
                callback(err,docs);
                dbCon.close();
            });
```

JSON Structure:

```
"employees":[
    {"_id":1, "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"_id":2, "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"_id":3,"lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

When I first insert this JSON into mongodb, it gets inserted without any errors.
When I try insert again on the same database, with below JSON

```
"employees":[
    {"_id":2, "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"_id":5, "lastName":"Peter"}, 
    {"_id":6,"``lastName":"James"}
]
```

Now the mondo db is throwing duplicate key error.
Is there any way where I can omit the "_id":2 and insert "_id":5 and "_id":6 into mongo?

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter) in your case :

```
db.people.update(
   { name: "Andy" },
   {
      name: "Andy",
      rating: 1,
      score: 1
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

If the first query gets a blank collection, that it will insert the data in this case if a Recrod with name Andy is not there, it will insert one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but update is not working and an error is being thrown when trying to update it

Answer (score 0):

In the first time, you insert a document 
`{"_id":2, "lastName":"Smith"}`.

In the second time , you insert a document `{"_id":2, "lastName":"Smith"}`.

Their ids are the same ,not unique.

Suggest create id automatically by mongdb.

You can add the following code:

```
collection.findOne({"_id":2}.exec(function(err,result){
   if(!result){
      collection.insert(XXX);
   }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I need to omit the records which has the same ID and insert the remaining records with different ID's.
Please let me know if there is any other alternative

Comment: You can judge whether the document exists in mongodb. If it exists, you can ignore the insertion.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to ignore the insertion on one record and proceed with other